Go through an object to sum the number of children
I feel like this is an easy solve, but I've been stuck for a while, so thought I'd reach out for help.
I have an array of objects as per below.
songs = [
  { 
    track_name: "name of track" , 
    track_genres: ["chamber pop","indie pop"] },
  { 
    track_name: "name of track 2" , 
    track_genres: ["dutch r&b","indie soul", "indie pop"] },
  { 
    track_name: "name of track 3" , 
    track_genres: ["indie pop","chamber pop","indie soul"] }
]

I will then make a "mapping" object so each child gets a parent genre assigned to them. I shall be doing this manually (if you have ideas on doing it automatically through code, that'd be great too, but not the core issue for the question)
genres = [
  {
    name: "Pop",
    children: [{name:"Chamber Pop"},{name:"Indie Pop"}]
  },
  {
    name: "R&B",
    children: [{name:"Dutch R&B"}]
  },
  {
    name: "Soul",
    children: [{name:"Indie Soul"}]
  }
]

I now want to run through all tracks in "songs" and populate the size in the respective children of genres. Ideal Output should be:
genres = [
  {
    name: "Pop",
    children: [{name:"Chamber Pop", size:2},{name:"Indie Pop", size:3}]
  },
  {
    name: "R&B",
    children: [{name:"Dutch R&B", size:1}]
  },
  {
    name: "Soul",
    children: [{name:"Indie Soul", size:2}]
  }
]

Any help on this would be appreciated. I'll be using javascript for this, happy to use lodash/underscore as well if it's more efficient.
I know how to loop through tracks, but once I have a particular child genre, I'm not able to efficiently map it to the genres variable

Please visit [ask] and make us a [mcve]

You can use forEach() to iterate over the genres and each children array. Now you can find out how often the genre is used by filtering the songs array by genre. Note that you have mixed casing in the songs and genres array. I solved it by using toLowerCase(), but you may want to fix your data instead.


const songs = [
  {
    track_name: "name of track",
    track_genres: ["chamber pop", "indie pop"],
  },
  {
    track_name: "name of track 2",
    track_genres: ["dutch r&b", "indie soul", "indie pop"],
  },
  {
    track_name: "name of track 3",
    track_genres: ["indie pop", "chamber pop", "indie soul"],
  },
];
const genres = [
  {
    name: "Pop",
    children: [{ name: "Chamber Pop" }, { name: "Indie Pop" }],
  },
  {
    name: "R&B",
    children: [{ name: "Dutch R&B" }],
  },
  {
    name: "Soul",
    children: [{ name: "Indie Soul" }],
  },
];
genres.forEach(({ children }) => {
  children.forEach((child) => {
    child.size = songs.filter((song) =>
      song.track_genres.includes(child.name.toLowerCase()),
    ).length;
  });
});
console.log(genres);



Note that this solution mutates the genres array. If you want to keep the genres array as-is and generate a new array, you should use map() instead of forEach() and return the modified data.

Step 1: make a function to count the number of song on each track genre
Step 2: add the result to each name in children


const songs = [
  { 
    track_name: "name of track" , 
    track_genres: ["chamber pop","indie pop"] },
  { 
    track_name: "name of track 2" , 
    track_genres: ["dutch r&b","indie soul", "indie pop"] },
  { 
    track_name: "name of track 3" , 
    track_genres: ["indie pop","chamber pop","indie soul"] }
]
const genres = [
  {
    name: "Pop",
    children: [{name:"Chamber Pop"},{name:"Indie Pop"}]
  },
  {
    name: "R&B",
    children: [{name:"Dutch R&B"}]
  },
  {
    name: "Soul",
    children: [{name:"Indie Soul"}]
  }
]
function countSongs(genre){
  return songs.filter(s => s.track_genres.map(g => g.toLowerCase())
  .includes(genre.toLowerCase())).length
}
const genresResult = genres.map(g => {
  return {...g, children: g.children.map(c=>{
    return {...c, size: countSongs(c.name)}
  })}
})
console.log(genresResult)
.as-console-wrapper {max-height:100% !important}




You could first group by the track_genres of each track in songs by using Map.groupBy on an array of flattened track_genres. Once you have this grouped map, you can use .map() on your genres array to transform each object to change the children array, where you can map each object in that array to have a size property which uses the previously created Map to get the length of the grouped array for the current child.name:


const songs = [{ track_name: "name of track", track_genres: ["chamber pop", "indie pop"] }, { track_name: "name of track 2", track_genres: ["dutch r&b", "indie soul", "indie pop"] }, { track_name: "name of track 3", track_genres: ["indie pop", "chamber pop", "indie soul"] } ];
const genres = [{ name: "Pop", children: [{ name: "Chamber Pop" }, { name: "Indie Pop" }] }, { name: "R&B", children: [{ name: "Dutch R&B" }] }, { name: "Soul", children: [{ name: "Indie Soul" }] } ];

const genreMap = Map.groupBy(songs.flatMap(obj => obj.track_genres), genre => genre);
const res = genres.map(genre => ({
  ...genre,
  children: genre.children.map(child => ({
    ...child,
    size: genreMap.get(child.name.toLowerCase())?.length ?? 0
  }))
}));

console.log(res);




and what if I need to add the parent genres back into the songs variable?

This version should be more efficient since it only loops through all the songs once, to populate the size properties of the subgenre objects, by using a previously built auxiliary object with the the references of the subgenres with the method groupBy:


const songs = [
  {
    track_name: "name of track",
    track_genres: ["chamber pop", "indie pop"],
  },
  {
    track_name: "name of track 2",
    track_genres: ["dutch r&b", "indie soul", "indie pop"],
  },
  {
    track_name: "name of track 3",
    track_genres: ["indie pop", "chamber pop", "indie soul"],
  },
];
const genres = [
  {
    name: "Pop",
    children: [{ name: "Chamber Pop" }, { name: "Indie Pop" }],
  },
  {
    name: "R&B",
    children: [{ name: "Dutch R&B" }],
  },
  {
    name: "Soul",
    children: [{ name: "Indie Soul" }],
  },
];
const auxGenres = genres.reduce((acc, genre) => {
  return {...acc, ...Object.groupBy(genre.children, ({name}) =>
    name.toLowerCase())};
}, {});
songs.forEach(({track_genres}) => {
  track_genres.forEach(genre => {
    auxGenres[genre.toLowerCase()][0].size ??= 0;
    auxGenres[genre.toLowerCase()][0].size++;
  });
});
console.log(genres);




and what if I need to add the parent genres back into the songs variable?

@NNS Could you please give an example of expected output?

const songs = [
{
track_name: "name of track",
track_genres: ["chamber pop", "indie pop"],
parent_genres: ["Pop"],
},
{
track_name: "name of track 2",
track_genres: ["dutch r&b", "indie soul", "indie pop"],
parent_genres: ["R&B","Soul","Pop"],
},
{
track_name: "name of track 3",
track_genres: ["indie pop", "chamber pop", "indie soul"],
parent_genres: ["Pop", "Soul"],
},
];
